# create tuple with 4 elements using tuple with 3 elements and an extra object

Tags: scala, apache-spark, tuples

I have a tuple of type `(Array[Short], Array[Short], Array[Short])`.
Now I want a tuple with elements should be something like
`(Array[Short], Array[Short], Array[Short]) + Obj`

basically am creating a map, to check tuple with 3 elements, if found then create a new tuple with those 3 elements and a fourth also.

```
val obj1: collection.mutable.HashMap[String, (Array[Short], Array[Short], Array[Short])] = HashMap.empty
val combJoinedMap: collection.mutable.HashMap[String, (Array[Short], Array[Short], Array[Short], Object)] = HashMap.empty
```

Comment: 1. how does that relate to spark? 2. what have you tried? at least provide expected input and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever the type of `reducedCreditStage3ARddMapped`. You are getting `Option[Array[Short]]` here because `.get` from a `Map` returns optional, and then you are combining `Option[Array[Short]]` with some type which is code smell here.

without knowing the type of `crdStgRdd._2` I can say you can do something like this:

```
val t: Array[Short] = combMap.getOrElse(crdStgRdd._1), Array.empty[Short]), 
val XXX = Array.empty[Short]
combJoinedMap.put(crdStgRdd._1,  (t, crdStgRdd._2, XXX))
```

you need to replace XXX third element of the tuple with something meaningful or you should have a structure like this in you `reducedCreditStage3ARddMapped`.

`val  reducedCreditStage3ARddMapped: HashMap[String, (Array[Short], Array[Short])]`

NOTE: please be a specific with your types and clear about error, otherwise people should just guess and won't be able to help.

Comment: @anurag1007 you can accept my answer if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collect` to filter and change each element in one go as following:

```scala
  val map: Map[String, (Array[Short], Array[Short], Array[Short])] = Map.empty 
  val combJoinedMap = map.collect {
    case (key, (array1, array2, array3)) if true /*check whatever condition you need*/ =>
      key -> (array1, array2, array3, new Object)
  }
```

Partial function `case (key, (array1, array2, array3)) ...` deconstructs the key and value, as a tuple of 3 elements, into each separate component.

Comment: am tryig to put in a map based on the codition if key is present in 1st map.

Comment: in this case just do a map instead of collect

Answer (score -1):

am tryig to put in a map based on the codition if key is present in 1st map. this is what am tryng to do:

val combMap: collection.mutable.HashMap[String, (Array[Short], Array[Short], Array[Short])] = HashMap.empty
    val combJoinedMap: collection.mutable.HashMap[String, (Array[Short], Array[Short], Array[Short], Object)] = HashMap.empty

```
  combinationRdd.foreach(combRdd =>{
    combMap.put(combRdd._1, (combRdd._2._1, combRdd._2._2, combRdd._2._3))
  })

  reducedCreditStage3ARddMapped.foreach(crdStgRdd =>{
    if(combMap.contains(crdStgRdd._1))
        combJoinedMap.put(crdStgRdd._1, ((combMap.get(crdStgRdd._1)) + crdStgRdd._2))
  })
```

but  combJoinedMap.put(crdStgRdd._1, ((combMap.get(crdStgRdd._1)) + crdStgRdd._2)) giving error

Comment: can you show the type of the `reducedCreditStage3ARddMapped`?